# "ReferenceError: document is not defined" for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, referenceerror

I'm working on a Chrome extension and encountering an error that says "ReferenceError: document is not defined" when running the command "node popup.js" in the terminal of Visual Studio Code. Here are some additional details:

**Directory Structure:** All files, including **`popup.html`**, **`popup.js`**, **`database.js`**, and **`manifest.json`**, are located in the same directory.

**Node.js and SQL:** Node.js and SQL are both installed and configured properly on my system.

Now, let's take a closer look at the code:

popup.html is simple what is inside of the popup when clicking on the extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ARQ Database</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Add person to database</h3>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Age" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="nationality" placeholder="Nationality" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Description" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js is supposed to add a new person to the database:

```
popup.js
const db = require('./database.js');
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
console.log("FUNCTION RUNNING...")

submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    let age = document.querySelector("#age").value;
    let nationality = document.querySelector("#nationality").value;
    let description = document.querySelector("#description").value;

    let values = [name, age, nationality, description];

    newPerson(values);
});

function newPerson(values) {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO people (name, age, nationality, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    db.query(sql, values, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("PERSON ADDED TO DATABASE");
    });
}
```

database.js keeps phpmyadmin running in the background as well as the sql table:

```
// database.js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'ARQ'
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('RUNNING...');
});

module.exports = db;
```

manifest.json is simply how the chrome store shows my chrome extension within the chrome store.

```
{
    "name": "ARQ Database",
    "version": "0.01",
    "description": "An easy way to find the best fit for the job.",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Database Popup",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "database.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "popup.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: NodeJs is a different environment to the browser. It doesn't understand what `document` is. A cursory look at your code indicates that you're mixing up server/client code.

Comment: Im pretty sure that you can't run MySQL in an extension like that